# Drawing application with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

for the past week, I've been looking for a way to create an application with Unity, in which I will be able to create drawings.

Something like this:

[image: drawing application]

I've tried several ways to simulate drawing, but none of them accomplished why I expected.

What would you say to be the recommended way to achieve this?
I tried using SetPixel & GetPixel, but since editing textures at runtime can be very slow, I'm looking for a better way, if there's any.

Thanks.

Comment: Googling this a found a simple tutorial straight away https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx5U1ZaZ080

Comment: @akaBase Thank you, but I know how to Google. If you watch the video, you would see that I'm not looking to Instantiate dots, which would be horrible as a painting application - I need to draw smooth lines.

Comment: That was part 1, if you go to the end of part 2 you will see how to do it. the dots are the 1st step towards your goal., I just figured Id link you the start of the tutorial and you would see it is part 1

Comment: @akaBase Umm, He clearly states in part 2, in the comments section, that he didn't find a way to connect the dots.

Comment: I would write an answer for this but I don't have a lot of time available atm, I will write one tonight if you are still having problems but the way I would approach it is, 1 create a script that creates a texture 2d, checks for mouse input, if the mouse button is down, it converts that position to a pixel position on the texture2d and writes a color to that pixel.  At the end of update I would have a reference to a RawImage and set that RawImages texture to the texture you are writing to.

Comment: @Eddge Thank you, would it work smoothly in your opinion? because manipulating textures at runtime can be very slow. Let me know what you think. If you somehow find time for it as you mentioned, I would be very grateful, as I'm struggling with this for too long (way more than I thought). thanks again.

Comment: I cannot gurantee it would be fast, as it would really depend on the texture size you are trying to edit, however RawImages in Unity are typically used to read data from camera's so off of the top of my head I do not believe it would be slow,  I'll run some tests and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this with a relatively large texture but I painted a happy face with it, I have comments explaining whats going on in the code, the best way to use this is using the Unity Menu and creating a RawImage then attaching this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(RawImage))]
public class PaintCanvas : MonoBehaviour
{

    RectTransform rt;
    RawImage ri;
    Vector3 bottomLeft = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 topRight = Vector3.zero;
    Texture2D canvas;

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Getting the RectTransform, since this is a RawImage, which exists on the canvas and should have a rect transform
        rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        if (rt != null)
        {
            GetWorldCorners();
        }
        // RawImage that we are going to be updating for our paint application.
        ri = GetComponent<RawImage>();
        if (ri != null)
        {
            CreateTexture2D();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Make sure our stuff is valid
        if (rt != null)
        {
            if(ri != null)
            {
                HandleInput();
            }
        }
    }

    void HandleInput()
    {
        // Since we can only paint on the canvas if the mouse button is press
        // May be best to revise this so the tool has a call back for example a 
        // fill tool selected would call its own "Handle" method,

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector2Int mousePos = Vector2Int.zero;
            // We have input, lets convert the mouse position to be relative to the canvas
            ConvertMousePosition(ref mousePos);
            // Checking that our mouse is in bounds, which is stored in our height and width variable and as long as it has a "positive value"
            if(MouseIsInBounds(mousePos))
            {
                // This method could be removed to be the tool method I mention above
                // you would pass in the mousePosition, and color similar to this.
                // This way each tool would be its "own" component that would be activated
                // through some form of UI.
                PaintTexture(mousePos, Color.black); // Also the color you want would be here to...
            }

            Debug.Log(mousePos);
        }
    }

    void PaintTexture(Vector2Int pos, Color color)
    {
        // In our method we don't allow transparency and we are just replacing the pixel,
        canvas.SetPixel(pos.x, pos.y, color);
        // Applying out change, we dont want to mip levels.
        // If you are doing some blending or transparency stuff that would be handled by your tool
        canvas.Apply(false);
    }

    bool MouseIsInBounds(Vector2Int mousePos)
    {
        // The position is already relative to the texture so if it is >= to 0 and less then the texture
        // width and height it is in bounds.
        if(mousePos.x >= 0 && mousePos.x < width)
        {
            if (mousePos.y >= 0 && mousePos.y < height)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void ConvertMousePosition(ref Vector2Int mouseOut)
    {
        // The mouse Position, and the RawImage position are returned in the same space
        // So we can just update based off of that
        mouseOut.x = Mathf.RoundToInt(Input.mousePosition.x - bottomLeft.x);
        mouseOut.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(Input.mousePosition.y - bottomLeft.y);
    }

    void CreateTexture2D()
    {
        // Creating our "Draw" texture to be the same size as our RawImage.
        width = Mathf.RoundToInt(topRight.x - bottomLeft.x);
        height = Mathf.RoundToInt(topRight.y - bottomLeft.y);
        canvas = new Texture2D(width, height);
        ri.texture = canvas;
    }

    void GetWorldCorners()
    {
        if (rt != null)
        {
            Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
            rt.GetWorldCorners(corners);

            // Setting our corners  based on the fact GetCorners returns them in clockwise order starting from BL TL TR BR.
            bottomLeft = corners[0];
            topRight = corners[2];
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to point out depending on your scale, and how fast you move the mouse you may end up with dots, that is because this algorithim only updates the pixels that mouse is over per frame, if you move the mouse faster then 1 px per frame you will have gaps, this can be resolved by storing the mousePosition last frame, getting the new position this frame, and creating a line, then updating all points on that line.

Comment: Hi Eddge, thank you for sharing your code. Is there an option to make the 'brush' shaped as a circle instead of a square? If I think of copying a circle shaped texture everytime, that wouldn't run smoothly

Comment: @sisimendel well in the code I wrote a comment about where you could make a tool, and then call that tools paint method, if you want it to be circlular then in that tools paint method you would do it, which would basically just be a radius and looping over the pixels within that radius.