# Draw thick, soft line onto texture in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Given a 2D drawing app in 3D space (think a flat quad surface in VR), and given a blank Texture2D/ RawTextureData of NativeArray, how might one draw a line from point a to b, but using a specific line width (thickness), as well as ideally antialiasing? Thanks!

Comment: You could use a LineRenderer

Comment: @Jichael not sure that would work to write blank Texture2D, though I would be curious to see your approach using a LineRenderer for it.

Comment: I would start by looking @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866727/drawing-application-with-unity/55871068#55871068  It will get you started on writing on a texture 2d in 3d space.  Then to draw along a line, you will need to calculate a direction vector from a to b, loop through each pixel along that way and draw to them.  your width would be a vector perpendicular to your direction vector looped a set number of times in that direction and -direction.  softness would be less an interpolation between your color and the color on the texture already depending on the distance form the line.

Comment: LineRenderer is indeed a fallback I'm eying. While it's not directly applicable to 2D pixels, one could either fake it to look similar, or occasionally have a camera snapshot the line-renderings to then via a renderTexture properly paint it into the texture2D or so. At least it's smooth & fluid by default! Another workaround I'm eying is to stamp a 2D line sprite onto the surface, scaled and rotated so that it will create a proper line part.